# problem with paypal express checkout form?

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

im facing a huge problem regarding paypal express checkout form .
once i click check out button its drive me to the paypal home page .
no payment options no amount to pay nothing at it all just the normal paypal home page

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type=hidden name="USER" value="payment_api1.XXXXX.com"> 
        <input type=hidden name="PWD" value="XXXXXXXXX"> 
        <input type=hidden name="SIGNATURE" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"> 
        <input type=hidden name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="500"> 
        <input type=hidden name="RETURNURL" value="http://xxxx.net"> 
        <input type=hidden name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" value="GBP">
        <input type=hidden name="CANCELURL" value="http://xxxx.net"> 
        <input type="image" src="images/checkout-button.png" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

this the simple form but i realy don't know why its not working at it all

Comment: Why would you have pwd and signature in there? that would be viewable by anyone who could click on it...seems like a security risk. try setting up your button from scratch by logging into the paypal console with the username and password it came from

Answer (score 0):

This is a test form for testing purposes only. You should not ever, ever, use this in a live environment (besides, it wouldn't work anyway).

To answer your question: replace https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr by https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp or https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp, depending on whether you're working in the live or sandbox environment.

Are you a developer? Express Checkout is an API-based solution. While fairly easy to implement, it does require you to have some programming skills. If you're not a developer, use Website Payments Standard instead.